# Android studio not recognizing USB Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I'm having ENOURMOUS issues with android studio. If it's not rendering issues it's the emulator. (btw Must I have internet connection to use that IDE ? Must I only use SDK setting of SDK actually installed on my machine))
My current problem is that I followed this hello world tutorial https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html
Then this http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html
My cellphone is ALCATEL TOUCH M'POP 5020D. I want to use it to run my app. So I have enabled it's debugging mode. But Android studio is not detectitng it BUT the phone is in debugging mode. Please what should I do ?  Even when I try using an emulator it does not work. (my minimum SDK for the project and emulator is API 19)
Both the emulator and the phone is not working

[image]

**SDK Extras screenshotS**

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you install the driver for the mobile usb?

Comment: in linux i always have to set my device in `PTP` mode

Comment: @vsambor I don't what what driver you are referring to. When I connect my phone to my Windows PC everything works perfectly

Comment: just try to instal mtk driver... maybe there is something missing and see if it works, it's not a big deal to instala a driver

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the MTK Driver ([here is the download link](https://androidmtk.com/download-mtk-usb-all-drivers))

 
And be sure that you enabled *development settings* and the usb debugging feature under Settings -> About Phone -> Advanced settings.

Comment: hmmm I'm not sure your MTK driver is safe. WOT red flagged the website you gave me. (I love computer security. Not too sure about downloads from red flagged websites.) THe devellopement settings have been set

Comment: then check from another website, I took the first google gave me :)

Comment: Did you even have to do this for yourself in the past ?